# Is $y=x^3$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ a globally one-to-one and onto function?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

This is from Mathematics for Economists by Simon and Blume (Page 367, Theorem 15.9)

> The inverse function theorem is a powerful result. In general, it is nearly impossible to check directly that a given map is one-to-one and onto.By the inverse function theorem, we only show that its derivative is a nonsingular matrix, a much easier task.

Now isn't $y=x^3$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ a globally one-to-one and onto function though $\frac{dy}{dx}=3x^2$ is singular for $x=0$, a contradiction?

Comment: The inverse function theorem just doesn’t apply at $x=0$, but the function is still one-to-one and onto. No contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inverse function theorem tells you that if $\frac{\text dy}{\text dx}>0$ for all $x$, then there will be an inverse.  However, this is not an iff statement, and you certainly don't need it for $x^3$, which has the trivial inverse $x^{1/3}$ which is well-defined for all $x\in\Bbb R$.

Once you have an inverse, bijection is easy to prove.  Since a function must map all elements of the domain to the codomain, $f$ must be onto.  Otherwise, there would be some value in the range which the inverse could not map into the domain.  Additionally, if $f$ is not one-to-one, then the inverse must map one value to two, so it is not well-defined.  By the contrapositive, $f$ must be one-to-one.

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't a contradiction. The inverse function theorem just states, that if $D_f(x)$ is non-singular, then there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ so that $f$ is bijective on $U$.

It is a sufficent, but not neccessary for $D_f(x)$ to be non-singular.